Laravel 11 - I want to create dynamic routing for multi level access but without passing the same parameter each time
In laravel 11 i setup my route like this :
      then: function(){
                Route::middleware(['web', 'admin'])->prefix('admin')->name('admin.')->group(base_path('routes/admin.php'));
                Route::middleware(['web', 'user'])->prefix('u/{userid?}')->name('user.')->group(base_path('routes/user.php'));
            },

but there is a problem when i want to each any route of user.php file: i need to add userid parameter each time
can i automate this process so the userid will automatically injected to the route
I don't want to write this type of syntax each time :
<a href="{{ route("user.comment.create", Auth::id()) }}"></a>

I think laravel have the good approach for this : I want to use that approach !
anyone tell me the right way to do this...
